# How to add blocks into a dispenser without clearing blocks in it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a map and I need to find a way to be able to add blocks into a dispenser without clearing the items that are already in it. I have looked everywhere/tried everything and I'm afraid that all the time I have used on the map is a waste.

I have done `/setblock`, `/entitydata`. I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/setblock` a hopper directly above the dispenser with the items in it that you want to add. For example, to add a stack of arrows:

```
/setblock X Y Z hopper 0 replace {Items:[{id:arrow,Count:64}]}
```

You can remove the hopper afterwards with another `/setblock` command if you need to.

Comment: i need to add 64 of the item, hoppers wont fill the dispenser fast enough

Comment: @Furryblaze Try a hopper on each side? I didn't realize there was a time limit.

Comment: there are 8 teams, is it possible to put it straight into the dispencer by command block? but i will try your idea

Comment: @Furryblaze Just remembered that you could also speed up a hopper's transfer rate by setting the hopper's "TransferCooldown" to 1 on a clock.

Comment: wow thx i will try it

Comment: what command do i use to summon a hopper with transfercooldown to 1?

Comment: don't worry, i found it and i think its going to work, ill post the map when its done

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple, if you are just adding more if a single block use a hopper on the top of it... if you are trying to add more blocks than there is spaces... sadly it isn't quite possible - unless you use a comparator to detect when the dispenser is empty then using a command block fill it with different items. Hope the helped, if you have any further information... tell me :)

Comment: to elaborate, i need to testfor 8 teams, for each team that is found i need to add 64 of a certain command block, 1 type for each team.

Answer (score 0):

This depend on if you mean multiple different items or more of the same, if it is the former the I suggest placing a hopper on top of the dispenser, if it's the latter I suggest just left-clicking to place a portion of stack inside the dispenser